# Is there any announced or expected/estimated date for the deprecation of Spark Data Source API V1

Tags: apache-spark, databricks

I am utilizing the v3.0.1 of the spark-mongo connector and it is a legacy connector now, but I am using it because I am facing an issue with the new v10 connector.

I read a blog post from MongoDB that they will support this v3 connector until Spark Data Source API V1 is supported.

> The current version of the MongoDB Spark Connector was written in 2016 and is based on Version 1 of the Spark Data Source API. This API is still supported, but Databricks has released an updated version of the API, making it easier for data sources like MongoDB to work within the Spark ecosystem. By using Version 2 of the MongoDB Spark Connector, you’ll immediately benefit from capabilities such as tighter integration with Spark Structured Streaming.
>
> MongoDB will continue to support Version 1 until Databricks deprecates its Datasource API, but no new features will be implemented, and upgrades to the Connector will include only bug fixes and support for the current version.

Source: https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/new-mongodb-spark-connector

Tried searching on the Internet but was not able to find any dates or timelines.
This is important for us because I don't want to implement the Data Pipelines on top of a library that might be deprecated soon